# what ASCII characters are these?

Tags: php, string, ascii

I have two characters that I need to do a search and replace on in a php-string.

1. `’`
2. `“`

Somehow these are different from:

1. `'`
2. `"`

Does anyone know what function I might use to strip these from a php string?

Comment: The first two aren't in ASCII. They're (in)famous as "smart/fancy quotes", mainly come from a certain office suite \*cough\* and aren't a problem if your website specifies in a certain encoding - which sadly is incompatible with Unicode though. (Now, to be fair, there should be equivalents in Unicode - propably what SO uses right now)

Comment: this lovely characters have been a major encoding pain for me during a very long period.

Comment: If you're dealing with those characters, you'll probably also encounter that en dash (`–`), too. Pretty annoying if you're not using UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what happens when someone sends you an email in outlook, so watch out, because you're totally missing the opening pair of those single quotes, and closing pair for the double quotes. [But really, you need to be using html entity codes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html).

Why? Because there's a hell of a lot more out there in the wilderness than those two codes you posted above, in-fact, you've only shown half the set of quotes (ie, you missed the closing single quote, and opening double quote). There's hundreds, you need to be encoding them in a better way than string replace.

There's a couple ways to manage the translation from encoding to html entity.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

http://piology.org/entities.html

http://konieczny.be/unicode.html

There's more also, but they basically do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a PHP script saved as UTF-8 (so that these chars are correctly replresented), you can simply use `str_replace` to strip them.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is called smart quotes, or curly quotes. There are people doing similar things.
[Chris Shiflett](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3adqAiPfk5qz0J%3ashiflett.org/blog/2005/oct/convert-smart-quotes-with-php%20ascii%20smart%20quotes&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a&source=www.google.com)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, I have been using it and it works:

[How To Clean Special Characters From PHP String](http://www.bala-krishna.com/how-to-clean-special-characters-from-php-string/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [**`str_replace`**](https://www.php.net/str_replace) ?

```
$new_str = str_replace(array('’', '“'), '', $str);
```

*Of course, this requires your PHP scripts to be saved as UTF-8.*

And if this doesn't work because those characters cannot be properly written using UTF-8, you'll have to fallback to using their hexadecimal representations.

For example :

```
$new_str = str_replace(array('\xC2\x91', '\xC2\x93'), '', $str);
```

*(Not sure the hexadecimal values I used are really those of your two special quotes, though)*